# How to change the size of an image using in the modal footer?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I am working on laravel 5.0. I am using the bootstrap feature i.e; modal.I just want to add an image in the modal content. I am getting the image but couldn't able to adjust the size of that image.Also,By using css, there is no effect on the image size.

My Code:

```html
 @foreach($gallery->images as $image)
 <section id="gal" class="col-md-3">

 <a class="col-md-3" href="" data-toggle="modal" 
 data-target="#yourModal{{ $image->id }}">
 <img src="{{ url($image->file_path)    }}"></a>

 </section>
 @endforeach

  @foreach($gallery->images as $image)
  <div class="modal fade" id="yourModal{{ $image->id }}" 
  tabindex="-1"   role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
   aria-label="Close">&times;</button>

    </div>
   <div id="modalimage1" class="modal-body">
   <img id="modalimage" src="{{ url($image->file_path) }}">
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
   <div class="row">
   <section class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-2">
  <img  id="jumboimage" src="/src/images/g.jpg"/>
  </section>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```css
#modalimage{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
} 

#jumboimage{
    width:10px;
    height:15px;
}
```

Comment: May be some default bootstrap styles are taking effect here, try to create a sample jsfiddle to get appropriate help.

Comment: After implementing js, the size of an image changes but problem is that it is not working for all the modals. The image appears on the first position on my page,when i do click on that image , a modal appears on which i hv an image in the footer section of the modal . The size of that image in the footer is changing but it doesnt work for the other images on my page.

Comment: Sounds like your JS logic and CSS rules has to be checked to resolve your issue, is there anyway to see your page by direct URL or jsfiddle?